# How to limit the Process's CPU usage on Windows?

Tags: c++, window, cpu-usage

I need to control my application's CPU usage to a certain limit. My application will run on Win XP, Vista, Win7 and Windows 8.

I tried implementing to get the current process's CPU usage and using the Sleep() method.(I used  the APIs GetProcessTimes& GetSystemTimes)

pseudo code:

```
    for(;;)
    {
         //Get the current process's CPU Usage
         int cpuUsage  = CalculateCPUUsage();
         if(cpuUsage > 50)
             Sleep(10)
         else
        {
           //Project implementation code
        }    
    }
```

**Question:**

Can I write an application to monitor a process's CPU Usage and whenever the CPU reaches the allowed limit, stop the process and continue it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I believe you can monitor another process. But I don't think you can stop them without kernel-level privileges.

Comment: This sort of thing is just artificially making your program a lot slower than it needs to be.

Comment: Oops, I misread. You want to limit your own program's CPU usage. I read it as limiting *other* programs.

Comment: @Mysticial, you are right - you read correctly , I need to limit the current process cpu usage. either through current process's code or through other application(just a utility application - in unix I think we can do that)

Comment: Please tell what you are trying to achieve. Normally it's much better limiting a processes priority (or "niceness" in unix). It's what you can do by opening task manager in windows and setting a lower priority. I'm sure it's possible, but don't know about the API calls.

Comment: @Axel - I wan to limit my process's cpu usage programatically. ( as you said - I think I can try this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @JChan: You don't tell "why". Yes you can use `GetProcessTimes` and `Sleep`, and `SetPrirotyClass` and `SetProcessAffinityMask` as well. Still there is a smell around of your wrong approaching to the problem you have in first place.

Comment: @Roman, One of my colleque (Unix developer) suggested me to about  the  monitoring application.  That is the reason I posted  the above question to confirm this, Now I will  proceed with  GetProcessTimes and Sleep. Sorry for the ambiguity in my question

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the CPU usage of your process or any other process by adding the process of interest to a Job object, and placing limits on the Job object.

One of the resource limits which can be configured for Job objects is CPU usage:

- [`JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684147.aspx) available since Windows XP and 2003
- [`JOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448384.aspx) new in Windows 8 and Server 2012.

If you have to use the pre-Windows 8 approach, pay careful attention to the note:

> To register for notification when this limit is exceeded without terminating processes, use the SetInformationJobObject function with the JobObjectNotificationLimitInformation information class

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to give the process a lower priority in order to be nicer to other threads, you can set its priority with SetThreadPriority, e.g.:

```
SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL);
```